# System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I having an exception to this below class, after i have configured my Web.config can you please kindly assist me as its new to me.

```
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace ContentManagementSystem.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool ConfirmedEmail { get; set; }

    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB")// This is an exception, but i do have this schema on my sql server and its running on Windows mode not Server.
        {

        }
    }
}

<connectionStrings>
    <add name = "eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB" connectionString = "Data Source=GcobaniM-L\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=[DataDirectory]\eNtsaOnlineRegistrationDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=eNtsaOnlineRegistration;Integrated" Security="True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

; Integrated Security"... changed below.